# DBpedia URL specified rdfs:label not working

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

Here I have SPARQL query for DBpedia, to get all the properties for an item.

Usually I do specify ?item by its short label name, just like `?item rdfs:label "Reddit"@en .`. But here I'd like to specify the query with long URL like `?item rdfs:label <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Telegram_(software)> .`, since `?item rdfs:label "Telegram_(software)"@en .` does not work because of its parentheses. Also I tried `?item rdfs:label "Telegram_%28software%29"@en .` but not worked as well.

So, how can I use a long URL for rdfs:label on DBpedia? Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE
{
?item rdfs:label "Reddit"@en . # works 
# ?item rdfs:label <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Reddit> . # doesn't work for long url format 
# ?item rdfs:label <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Telegram_(software)> . # doesn't work for long url format 
?item ?prop ?tmp .
}
```

Comment: anything inside `<>` are URIs but `rdfs:label` needs literals, so I don't get what you're doing. `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Reddit>` is already the URI of the `?item`, so the query would be `select * where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Reddit> ?prop ?tmp}`

Comment: also, parentheses inside literals are not an issue, the query `select ?s where {?s rdfs:label "Telegram (software)"@en}` also works as expected

Comment: @UninformedUser oh understand. thanks for the info also, great help.